# Alpha-premult and y-flip are deprecated for non-DOM-Element uploads in mapbox

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Hello i try to use Mapbox for my web app, but when i try set lng 34.0544779,  and -118.2443409 i have problems
`Invalid LngLat latitude value: must be between -90 and 90`

When i remove center and create marker. 
`texImage2D: Alpha-premult and y-flip are deprecated for non-DOM-Element uploads.`

[image: This is my all code]

Answer (score 9):

> when i try set lng 34.0544779, and -118.2443409 i have problems Invalid LngLat latitude value: must be between -90 and 90

You are most likely setting the parameters in the wrong order. It must be [longitude, latitude]. So, [-118.244.409, 34.0544779].

> When i remove center and create marker. `texImage2D: Alpha-premult and y-flip are deprecated for non-DOM-Element uploads.`

You can ignore this. I don't know the cause, but I see this message all the time.

Comment: It looks like an issue that's been discussed for quite some time with firefox: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/5292 and unfortunately, looks like it won't be fixed.

Comment: still not apparently